# How do I stop a while loop if something happens inside a function that should stop the itterations?

Tags: python, while-loop

Hello fellow programmers! I am a beginner to python and a couple months ago, I decided to start my own little project to help my understanding of the whole development process in Python. I briefly know all the basic syntax but I was wondering how I could make something inside a function call the end of the while loop.

I am creating a simple terminal number guessing game, and it works by the player having several tries of guessing a number between 1 and 10 (I currently made it to be just 1 to test some things in the code).

If a player gets the number correct, the level should end and the player will then progress to the next level of the game. I tried to make a variable and make a true false statement but I can't manipulate variables in function inside of a while loop.

I am wondering how I can make it so that the game just ends when the player gets the correct number, I will include my code down here so you guys will have more context:

```
import random
import numpy
import time

def get_name(time):

    name = input("Before we start, what is your name? ")

    time.sleep(2)
    print("You said your name was: " + name)


# The Variable 'tries' is the indication of how many tries you have left
tries = 1

while tries < 6:

    def try_again(get_number, random, time):

        # This is to ask the player to try again
        answer = (input(" Do you want to try again?"))
        time.sleep(2)

        if answer == "yes":

            print("Alright!, well I am going to guess that you want to play again")
            time.sleep(1)

            print("You have used up: " + str(tries) + " Of your tries. Remember, when you use 5 tries without getting the correct number, the game ends")

        else:
            print("Thank you for playing the game, I hope you have better luck next time")
    

    def find_rand_num(get_number, random, time):

        num_list = [1,1]
        number = random.choice(num_list)

        # Asks the player for the number
        ques = (input("guess your number, since this is the first level you need to choose a number between 1 and 10  "))
        print(ques)

        if ques == str(number):
            time.sleep(2)

            print("Congratulations! You got the number correct!")
            try_again(get_number, random, time)


        elif input != number:
            time.sleep(2)

            print("Oops, you got the number wrong")
            try_again(get_number, random, time)
            
    def get_number(random, try_again, find_rand_num, time):
        
        # This chooses the number that the player will have to guess  
        time.sleep(3)              
        print("The computer is choosing a random number between 1 and 10... beep beep boop")
        time.sleep(2)

        find_rand_num(get_number, random, time)


    if tries < 2:
        get_name(time)
        tries += 1
        get_number(random, try_again, find_rand_num, time)

    else:
        tries += 1
        get_number(random, try_again, find_rand_num, time)


    if tries > 5:
        break
```

I apologize for some of the formatting in the code, I tried my best to look as accurate as it is in my IDE. My dad would usually help me with those types of questions but it appears I know more python than my dad at this point since he works with front end web development. So, back to my original question, how do I make so that if this statement:

```
    if ques == str(number):
        time.sleep(2)

        print("Congratulations! You got the number correct!")
        try_again(get_number, random, time)
```

is true, the while loop ends? Also, how does my code look? I put some time into making it look neat and I am interested from an expert's point of view. I once read that in programming, less is more, so I am trying to accomplish more with less with my code.

Thank you for taking the time to read this, and I would be very grateful if some of you have any solutions to my problem. Have a great day!

Comment: It may make your life easier if you moved the function definitions out of the loop (I'm assuming you want to define the functions only once) and only keep the actual code that is supposed to be looped inside. Then it will be clearer what happens and what is wrong.

Comment: when I used break this time, it works, but I may have used it incorrectly when I was trying to make the loop stop from the player getting the correct answert

Comment: You return from the function a number which sets 'tries' to be greater or equal to 6. This will stop the loop.

Comment: Ciaran, thank you for answering, is it ok if you elaborate a little bit more on it in the answer section please? I'm afraid I don't entirely understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were too many bugs in your code. First of all, you never used the parameters you passed in your functions, so I don't see a reason for them to stay there. Then you need to return something out of your functions to use them for breaking conditions (for example `True/False`). Lastly, I guess calling functions separately is much more convenient in your case since you need to do some checking before proceeding (Not inside each other). So, this is the code I ended up with:

```
import random
import time

def get_name():
    name = input("Before we start, what is your name? ")

    time.sleep(2)
    print("You said your name was: " + name)


def try_again():
    answer = (input("Do you want to try again? "))
    time.sleep(2)

    # Added return True/False to check whether user wants to play again or not
    if answer == "yes":
        print("Alright!, well I am going to guess that you want to play again")
        time.sleep(1)

        print("You have used up: " + str(tries) + " Of your tries. Remember, when you use 5 tries without getting the correct number, the game ends")
        return True

    else:
        print("Thank you for playing the game, I hope you have better luck next time")
        return False


# Joined get_number and find_random_number since get_number was doing nothing than calling find_rand_num
def find_rand_num():
    time.sleep(3)              
    print("The computer is choosing a random number between 1 and 10... beep beep boop")
    time.sleep(2)

    num_list = [1,1]
    number = random.choice(num_list)

    ques = (input("guess your number, since this is the first level you need to choose a number between 1 and 10  "))
    print(ques)

    if ques == str(number):
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Congratulations! You got the number correct!")
        # Added return to check if correct answer is found or not
        return "Found"
    elif input != number:
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Oops, you got the number wrong")


tries = 1
while tries < 6:
    if tries < 2:
        get_name()
    
    res = find_rand_num()
    if res == "Found":
        break

    checker = try_again()
    if checker is False:
        break
    
    # Removed redundant if/break since while will do it itself
    tries += 1
```

Comment: thank you so much! This is just what I was looking for.